# Adding parenthesis around highlighted text in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a functionality in Vim that allows parenthesis to be added around the highlighted text?

For instance, if I highlight  `n = getchar()` in `if (n = getchar() == '\n')`, I would want to put parenthesis around that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need an awesome and must-have plugin [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround). Then, it will happily do what you want if you select text and type `Sb` (surround-braces), or `S)` (note the capital S !).

It actually can do a lot of surrounding: various quotes, tags, etc. It allows you to put cursor in the double-quoted word and change double quotes to single quotes by typing: `cs"'` (change-surround `"` to `'`). Or you can completely delete quotes by typing `ds"` (delete-surround `"`).

Read the docs by link, it is really awesome!

Comment: You didn't explain how to do it with the selection, though. I got led here because it wasn't immediately obvious.

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard, what do you mean I didn't explain how to do it with the selection? The second sentense in my answer says:

> Then, it will happily do what you want if you **select text** and type `sb` (surround-braces), or `s)`.

Comment: So you did. Not working for me though, hitting `s` just deletes the selection and enters insert mode.

Comment: It means that the "surround" plugin I mentioned in my answer is not correctly installed.

Comment: Awsome indeed. I've been using it for a while and can bet.

Comment: no, you do not need a plugin...

Answer (score 37):

In addtition to Dmitry's suggestion of [the surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround), adding parenthesis around highlighted text can be done with the following command:

```
xi()<Esc>P
```

You can set a map in visual mode using (for example) `\s` by adding the following to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
xnoremap <leader>s xi()<Esc>P
```

Comment: This looks like a nice and simple solution. If I don't find any issues with this in the future, I'll prefer this over additional plugins. Thanks!

Comment: It's a good solution, but not quite as complete as using the surround plugin as it doesn't work if you are selecting whole lines (using `V` instead of `v`). In this case it just pastes the lines below your parens.

Comment: I had to use `di()<Esc>P` as `x` doesn't yank the selected word into a paste buffer for me. You can also use `vnoremap` for the shortcut to work in both visual and select modes, rather than just visual.

Comment: You can also record a macro as well.

Comment: Another variation: `c()<Esc>P`.

Answer (score 24):

## The command

`c()<Esc>P`

## Explanation

If you want to put the word under the cursor in to brackets this is `viwc()<Esc>P`.

`viw` will `v`isually select all charactrs `i`n a `w`ord.

`c()` will `c`change the selection and drops you into insert mode, where you type the literal characters `(` `)`. Also, `c` automatically copies the original content to your `yank` buffer (clip board).

With `<Esc>P` you return `Esc`back from insert to normal mode and `P`aste the previous content.

Comment: I think you want (capital) P so that the word is pasted between the parentheses instead of after them.

Answer (score 3):

Building on dotancohens answer, I put the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
xnoremap <leader>( <ESC>`>a)<ESC>`<i(<ESC>
```

You can easily make similar mappings for [], {}, etc. It works by jumping to the start and end markers implicitly set after ending visual mode. This way selecting whole lines will add the parens at the start/end of the first/last line; it won't overwrite your yank register; and it'll leave the cursor right before the opening paren.

Answer (score 1):

[lh-brackets](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/lhBrackets_default) simply binds `(` to surround the selection with the brackets. Unlike *surround* it doesn't follow the vim usual keybinding philosophy as does. Instead less keys are required.

Otherwise, there are many ways to proceed. If you don't mind messing the unnamed register, you also use `s(^R")<esc>` (`^R` like `CTRL-R`)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a bit more complex but it might be useful to someone.
I go the extra mile so that none of my registers get used by macros or functions.

```
function! WrapWith(startChar, endChar) range
    let l:beg = getpos("'<")
    let l:end = getpos("'>")
    execute "normal! `>a".a:endChar
    execute "normal! `<i".a:startChar
endfunction

"REMAPS

"Wrappers
vnoremap <silent> (( :call WrapWith("(", ")")<CR>
vnoremap <silent> [[ :call WrapWith("[", "]")<CR>
vnoremap <silent> {{ :call WrapWith("{", "}")<CR>
vnoremap <silent> << :call WrapWith("<", ">")<CR>
```

Some bonuses for ya:

```
augroup Clang
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType c,java,javascript setlocal formatoptions+=croq comments=sO:*\ -,mO:*\ ,exO:/{,exO:*/}
  autocmd FileType c,java,javascript,javascriptreact,scss inoremap <buffer> ** /**/<Left><Left>
  autocmd FileType c,java,javascript,javascriptreact,scss vnoremap <buffer> <TAB>/ :call WrapWith("/*","*/")<CR>
augroup END
```

No need for a plugin IMO.